# Coworker makes decisions he shouldn't be allowed to make

Tags: teamwork

Me: medior in ecommerce team
Him: manager in content team

Our teams are supposed to work together, them delivering the content to us, and we designing and developping to give the content a place on the platform.

However, he is making decisions as regards to coding and designing while he has no experience at all. He has no experience managing either, which causes him to try and manage basically 'everything'. If we design something he'll demand to have it the other way around, more often than not in ways that do not work for our customers at all. When I try to give feedback on what he does and try to explain that what we designed works better because we used certain theories or tests, he just waves it off. My CEO loves the guy and thinks everything he does is pure magic. If ie conversion rates go down because of a decision he made, our team gets blamed.

How do I professionally deal with this guy and tell him he should respect our thought-through and tested methods?

Comment: There are several questions on the topic of "non technical boss giving orders in a technical field", like [this one](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/70652/non-technical-manager-giving-nonsensical-implications) and [this one](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10989/convincing-a-technically-inexperienced-boss-to-not-interfere) - this is not an exhaustive list at all. Please have a look at them, they might help you ?

Comment: "*My CEO loves the guy*" Deal-breaker right there. I assume said CEO is the only person with management authority?

Comment: I could not find an answer in any of the questions I could find here as they all seem to focus on 'technical' problems, with the managers needing to learn more technical aspects, the OP being rude to manager etc, that's all not the case for me. I am looking for a way to make him understand that my 'tried and tested' method works better than his 'I like blue better' method.

Comment: @lilienthal yes, although the team manager now thinks he has powers of the same sort.

Comment: Well then for all intents and purposes he might as well be your actual boss. The linked question may be able to help in that case. Small companies with a "flat" hierarchy are notorious for dysfunction like this and I'm not sure there much advice we can give on a situation like that without knowing all the details (which would likely make the question off-topic).